# JavaScript syntax problem - Tip Calculator

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

Please, could you guys explain this syntax/expression problem?
I was practicing and I tried to create a Tip Calculator which will give me a tip value according to the bill value and percentage. 
I can not understand why the expression in the variable finalValues1 does not work.
[JSFiddle code result](https://jsfiddle.net/4yzcjuo0/4/). Thank you very much.

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    

    var bill, tip, percentage, finalValues1,  finalValues2;    
    bill = document.getElementById('bills').value;        

    if (bill < 50) { // if bill less $50, give tip of 20%.
        percentage = .2;

    } else if (bill > 50 && bill < 200) { // if bill greater $50 and less than $200, give tip of 15%. 
        percentage = .15; 

    }  else  {
        percentage = .1; // if bill greater than $200, give tip of 10%.

    }    

    tip = bill * percentage;

    // I want also to display the final value bills plus tip
    finalValues1 = bill + tip; // This code does not work, it is concatenating bills and tip. 
    finalValues2 = bill * 1 + tip; // this code works and it sums bill plus tip. WHY is that?
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Tip: " + tip + " and total bill plus tip test1: " + finalValues1 + " test2: " + finalValues2 ; 

});
```

Comment: Simple answer is an input `value` returns a string. In order to do numeric addition you need to convert that to number first. Lots of ways to convert to number...all easy to research. `"10" + 1` returns string `"101"`

Comment: Thank yous.
I missed something really simple...
element input returns a string.
I got confused with this input type="number", it is just for validation purposes.
I might have skipped this explanation in past years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bills.**value is a string** , not a number
if you want to get a number use bills.**valueAsNumber**
code:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')

myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let bill       = myForm.bills.valueAsNumber 
    , percentage = (bill < 50) ? 0.2 : (bill < 200) ? 0.15 : 0.1
    , tip        = bill * percentage
    ;
  myForm.demo.textContent = `Tip: ${tip.toFixed(2) } ___ total (bill + tip): ${(bill + tip).toFixed(2)}`
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form" >
  <output name="demo">???</output>
  <br>
  <br>  
  <label for="bills">Bill Value :</label>
  <input name="bills" autocomplete="off" type="number" required  step="0.01">
  <br>
  <br>  
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
 
</form>
```

as you see it is more easy to use form names instead of elements ID

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead `finalValues1 = Math.parseFloat(bill) + Math.parseFloat(tip);`

It'll force your code to treat both variables as floats (decimal numbers), rather than strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```js
function TipCalc(percent = 20){
  this.percent = percent; this.tip = this.total = 0;
  this.calc = bill=>{
    let t = this.percent/100*bill;
    this.tip = t.toFixed(2); this.total = (bill+t).toFixed(2);
    return this;
  }
}
const tc = new TipCalc;
function billTest(bill){
  let p;
  if(bill < 50){
    p = 20;
  }
  else if(bill < 200){
    p = 15; 
  }
  else{
    p = 10;
  }
  tc.percent = p; tc.calc(bill);
  console.log({percent:p, tip:tc.tip, total:tc.total});
}
billTest(15.72); billTest(200.01); billTest(50.01);
```

Note that `tipCalcInstance.tip` and `tipCalcInstance.total` are Strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the value as a float `bill = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bills').value);`

And you really should have 0's at the start of your decimals.

You also need to check your order of operations `finalValues2 = bill * 1 + tip`;

Since multiplication is applied first, this will always just be `(bill * 1) + tip`.

Change it to `bill * (1 + tip)`